# Drag + drop in Safari OSX

Tags: javascript, html, safari

It seems that Safari does not handle well drag-drop. In the snippet below, the green div does not follow the mouse pointer when dragged but follows it way to the right and lower down.

EDIT: when embedded here the green div is nowhere to be seen when dragged. This fiddle is better https://jsfiddle.net/8vckLerm/1/

I could not find any tricks to make it behave properly. Does anybody have any suggestion ?

Thanks

```js
function ods(ev) {
  console.log('START');
}

function od(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('DROP');
}

function odo(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('OVER');
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background: white;
}

div[draggable] {
  background: #cfc;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div ondragstart="ods(event)" draggable="true">
  Drag Me
</div>
<div ondrop="od(event)" ondragover="odo(event)">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: I know it's not asked in the question, but it doesn't work here on Firefox (Win 10). Same result here or in the fiddle: the green box doesn't follow the mouse, and only `START` is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `ods` function.

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vckLerm/2/)

```js
function ods(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  console.log('START');
}

function od(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('DROP');
}

function odo(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('OVER');
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background: white;
}

div[draggable] {
  background: #cfc;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div ondragstart="ods(event)" draggable="true">
  Drag Me
</div>
<div ondrop="od(event)" ondragover="odo(event)">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: this version with `ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);` makes it work on Firefox though